# Getting database constants and storing them in cache

Tags: c#, database, generics, caching, constants

Project info: WPF, PRISM, C# 4.0, WCF, Entity framework, SQL(express)

My database contains several "constants" e.g. a person has a classification -> Natural Person (ID = 1) or lawful person (ID = 2).

I want to get these constants out of the DB, and store them in the cache, so they can be used throughout the application, so they aren't "hard coded". I know you can store these constants in a static class, but this would only work if these constants don't change in the DB (and I don't want to rely on that fact).

My question is: how can I efficiently load these constants out of the DB and put them in my cache?

The following is how I've written it now, but it just doesn't feel right..

```
using (DetacheringenEntities objectcontext = new DetacheringenEntities())
{
   int natuurlijkPersoonClassificationResult = objectcontext.Classification.Where(c => c.Value == "Natuurlijk Persoon").Select(c => c.ClassificationID).SingleOrDefault();
   int rechtspersoonPersoonClassificationResult = objectcontext.Classification.Where(c => c.Value == "Rechtspersoon").Select(c => c.ClassificationID).SingleOrDefault();

   int klantPersonAgreementRoleResult = objectcontext.PersonAgreementInvolvementRole.Where(p => p.Value == "Klant").Select(p => p.PersonAgreementInvolvementRoleID).SingleOrDefault();  
   ... (about 10 more of these calls)    
}
```

After getting these out of the DB I put them in my cache:

```
 DefaultCacheProvider cacheProvider = new DefaultCacheProvider();
 cacheProvider.Set("NatuurlijkPersoon", natuurlijkPersoonClassificationResult, 30);
```

I make use of a Repository on my caching, so I can also unit test is later.

I've tried making a generic methode, but I failed terribly :P

```
private int GetDatabaseConstantValue<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, DetacheringenEntities context)
{
        int result = context
            .CreateQuery<T>(
            "[" + typeof(T).Name + "]")
            .Where(expression)
            .Select(typeof(T).Name + "ID").FirstOrDefault(); --> This doesn't work (obviously), but I want to select the ID of that table (which is always Tablename + ID).

        return result;
}
```

Any ideas of how I can solve this problem or make it better?

Thanks for any help!!

PS: Any tips are also appreciated :)

Comment: Isn't the text value "Natuurlijk Persoon" more likely to change than its ID number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just build a dictionary?

```
var classifications = objectcontext.Classification.ToDictionary(c => c.Value, c => c.ClassificationID);
```

Then you can retrieve the value:

```
classifications["Natuurlijk Persoon"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can I access "classifications" across multiple solutions? I've a "manager solution" which manages my WCF solutions, and in this manager solution I want to initiate the constants. When I work with this dictionary, can I use it in one of the "child" solutions? Thanks.
BTW: the dictionary is what I'm looking for, can I put a dictionary in my cache?

Comment: You should be able to put the dictionary into the cache. Once it is in the dictionary it is the same as any other C# object and has no connection etc back to the database. As for accessing across multiple solutions, that depends on your code...

Comment: If I can place it in my cache then I can access it :) Thanks a bunch for the help!